# How to modify styles dynamically at set intervals using javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, delay, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to dynamically add styles to an element after certain intervals, in order to create an animation effect using javascript alone. I've used setInterval() and am not able to clearInterval/ make it stop. Also, it isn't occurring at the intervals I'm assigning to the method - the animation seems to be occurring every one or two seconds.

Here is the code for what I've tried so far: http://codepen.io/AnkitaSood/pen/jyaqMR?editors=0010

Below is the logic that I need help with -

```
Object.keys(styles).forEach(function(key) {
    for(index = 0 ; index < styles[key].length; index++) {
      var intervals = setInterval(function(index) {
        elem.style[key] = styles[key][index];
      }, timer[index], index); 
    }
    clearInterval(intervals);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because only last `intervals` got cleared (your code keep overriding it). But even if you fix it, it wont't work as you expect as the `clearInterval` may immediately clear the interval even before the changes happen.

So I'm suggesting `setTimeout` instead:

```
this.animate = function() {
  for(index = 0 ; index < timer.length; index++) {
      setTimeout(function(index) {
        for (var key in styles) {
          elem.style[key] = styles[key][index];
        }
      }, timer[index], index); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Using `setTimeout` as suggested above helped me achieve the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are calling `setInterval` inside a loop. You don't need to do that because one call `setInterval` already loops for you (it will keep calling your callback every x milliseconds).  Your code actually starts a bunch of intervals and you probably only need one.

I modified it a bit like this and got some reasonable results:

```
this.animate = function() {
   var i = 0;

   setInterval(function() {
      elem.style['width'] = config.styles.width[i];
      elem.style['backgroundColor'] = config.styles.backgroundColor[i];
      i = ++i % 6;
  }, 1000);
};
```

This just runs the animation over and over again but hopefully it shows you how it can work. If you want to stop the interval after a certain number of loops you can do something like this:

```
this.animate = function() {
   var i = 0;

   var intId = setInterval(function() {
      elem.style['width'] = config.styles.width[i];
      elem.style['backgroundColor'] = config.styles.backgroundColor[i];

      if(++i >= 6) {
         clearInterval(intId);
      } 
   }, 1000);
};
```